# Getting word after ":" via the word before ":" using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following text:

```
var t="asdf  t1 : v1   xasdf  dfas sdf   t2 : v2  asdfad   t3 : v3   adsfasdf   t4 : v4";
```

How I can use regular expression to retrive values by its title?

I am looking for a solution like following:

```
t.match(/ ??? t2 ??? /);  //should return v2
```

Comment: what is your output looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

`t.match(/t2\s*:\s*(\w+)/)[1]` ?

Comment: It returns null, beside that you should (?=t2) or other mechanism to exclude t2 from output

Comment: Answer updated! You can get the output without t2, by taking the second value in the result array.

Comment: Yes. Isn't `t.match(/t2\s*:\s*(\w+)/)[1]` what you want?

Comment: OK, fixed answer so that it returns directly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is this simple I suggest to use just string manipulation functions rather than regexp. Split the file by lines then split each line by `:` and lastly trim labels and values.